# Ruby idiom for "foo.nil? ? nil : foo.to_i"?

Tags: ruby, idioms

```
def bar(foo)
  foo.nil? ? nil : foo.to_i
end
```

Any concise Ruby idiom for "foo.nil? ? nil : foo.to_i" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or a little bit shorter (if you dont expect `foo` to be `false`)

```
def bar(foo)
  foo.to_i if foo
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def bar(foo)
  foo.to_i unless foo.nil?
end
```

But you don't really gain anything, IMO, except eliminating the `? ?`. It's a character shorter, *potentially* more readable if you know Ruby. Don't know as it qualifies as "more concise" than the ternary.

(I say "potentially" because it might be considered non-obvious behavior in the `nil` case.)

Answer (score 3):

```
foo and foo.to_i
```

Boolean operators [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and return the value of the last expression evaluated.

- If `foo` *is* `nil`, it will be returned and `foo.to_i` will not be executed.
- If `foo` *is not* `nil`, `foo.to_i` will be evaluated and its result returned.

Answer (score 3):

If you use ActiveSupport from rails you can write it using `try` method

```
foo.try(:to_i)
```

Comment: Just a comment: `try` method is a Rails method, not Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to actually want the destructive version of this idiom, i.e.

```
foo = (foo.nil? ? nil : foo.to_i)
```

then you can do

```
foo &&= foo.to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the andand gem

http://andand.rubyforge.org/

This allows me to go:

```
foo.andand.to_i
```

which returns nil if foo is nil, or to_i else.

Answer (score 1):

The proper ruby idiom for this would be

```
foo && foo.to_i
```

However, [ruby 2.3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/) introduced the [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537), for [some reason](https://www.instagram.com/p/-M9l6mRPLR/) also known as "lonely operator" in the ruby community. Using that, you can write the same thing as:

```
foo&.to_i
```

to the same effect.

PS: some people [hate](http://rubinius.com/2016/01/11/nil-is-not-null-and-other-tales/) it.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

[**Idiomatic way to write Ruby code**](https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/idiomatic-ruby-1b5fa1445098).

We can write code in 4 different ways:

Using `if`:

```
def bar(foo)
  foo.to_i if foo
end
```

Using `unless`:

```
def bar(foo)
  foo.to_i unless foo.nil?
end
```

Using `try` method if using Rails:

```
def bar(foo)
  foo.try(:to_i)
end
```

Using `&.` operator (Ruby safe navigation operator) if using Ruby 2.3.x:

```
def bar(foo)
  foo&.to_i
end
```

For more [**Idiomatic way to write Ruby code**](https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/idiomatic-ruby-1b5fa1445098), I read an excellent post about that.